# C# Deserialize a Json string with one array and one bool value

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json string, but only the bool value is appending to my class, where as the array values are always null .

```
            public static EmployeeInformation GetEngineerAdditionInfo(ProjectUserRoles role)
            {
                    EmployeeInformation engineerAdditionalInfo = new EmployeeInformation();
                    var apiBaseUri = string.Empty;
                    apiBaseUri = "https:example.com";
                    Uri newUri = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUri);
                    httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                    httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            engineerAdditionalInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeInformation>(line);
                        }
                     }
              }
```

And my classes are

```
    public class EmployeeInformation
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        List<EmployeeBasicDetails> EmployeeBasicDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeBasicDetails
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Json string will be as follows,

```
{"IsSuccess":true,"EmployeeBasicDetails":[{"UserId":124,"EmployeeId":"SS124","EmailId":"example@example.com","EmployeeName":"Example"},{"UserId":125,"EmployeeId":"SS125","EmailId":"example@example.com","EmployeeName":"Example"},{"UserId":126,"EmployeeId":"SS126","EmailId":"example@example.com","EmployeeName":"Example"},{"UserId":127,"EmployeeId":"SS127","EmailId":"example@example.com","EmployeeName":"Example"}]}
```

Did i missed anything? Or is there any other way to get the array list from json string ?

Thanks in advance,

Dinesh.

Comment: Your EmployeeBasicDetails property in EmployeeInformation is not public. Check, if this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my day .. :) its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think you forgot to set your `EmployeeBasicDetails` to public:

```
public class EmployeeInformation
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeBasicDetails> EmployeeBasicDetails { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeBasicDetails
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps!